# My code returns an unexcpected value

Tags: c

Sorry for the generic question but I've come across a behaviour in my code that I can't explain and that I find relevant for further users.
There is the screenshot of my screen when it happend. It's a repeatable error that happend any time my code runs.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2smxg.png)
and there is the text version of it.
My code runs a function

```
inline static int isInBounds(SDL_Surface* img,int x,int y){
  if((x<0)||(x >= img->w)||(y<0)||(y >= img->h) ) return 0;
  return 1;
}
```

I ran my code using gdb and I got the results

```
(gdb) print isInBounds(surface,x,y)
$1 = 1
(gdb) print y >= surface->h
$2 = 1
```

I don't get it. If (y >= surface->h) = 1, shouldn't the function isInBounds(surface,x,y) return 0 since the if statement is fulfilled ?

Comment: Apparently [support for inline functions isn't universal](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Inline-Functions.html). It might help if you mention which compiler and which version of GDB you're using.

Comment: have you checked if the real return value from `isInBounds` is 1 or 0 rather than just `gdb`?

Comment: the values and types of `y` and `surface->h` would be interesting here.

Comment: Also, note that this occurs after a segfault, so some of the values may not be able to be trusted.

Comment: Also, you checked for y >= img->h twice

Comment: "shouldn't the function isInBounds(surface,x,y) return 0 "  No.  After a segfault, behavior is not defined.  Fix the cause of the seg  fault first.

Comment: gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9), GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.5) 7.11.1, y and surface->h are both int and their values are equals. For a little bit of context, I'm writing a C application with SDL2 library (for a school project). I have this program that runs, and iterate y over the height of an image (which is a SDL_Surface) and the segfault appears because I iterate until y reaches the very end of the height of the picture. isInBounds should check if the coordinate (x,y) is still inside the picture or out of bounds, but doesn't seems to work.

Comment: Add a printing statement in the function, showing all of `x`, `img->w`, `y` and `img-h`.

Comment: (`img->h`, of course)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error solved itself one day when I re-run it. Gods know what happened.